# c# datatable merge certain rows and columns of datatable

Tags: c#, merge, datatable

there are 6 columns inside datatable, I would like to merge both rows and columns of columns1/rows1 & column2/rows2 together but maintain the rest.Therefore, I had seperate the excess spacing by using split method but there are seperated data that I wanted to merge together like "ZPRP 09-0729-01-MAR" become "ZPRP09-0729-01-MAR"  Please help :D

Sample data : test1.txt

MY01                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               CISCO     ZPRP    08-0729-01-MAR       08-0729-01           1               EA
MY01                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               CISCO     ZPRP   08-0729-01-MAR       08-0729-01           1               EA
MY01                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               CISCO     ZPRP   08-0729-01-MAR       08-0729-01           1               EA
MY01                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               CISCO     ZPRP   10-2919-01$1         10-2919-01           1               EA
MY01                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               CISCO     ZPRP   10-2919-01$1         10-2919-01           1               EA
MY01

What i wanted result that display on datatable:

MY01                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               CISCO     ZPRP08-0729-01-MAR       08-0729-01           1               EA
MY01                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               CISCO     ZPRP08-0729-01-MAR       08-0729-01           1               EA
MY01                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               CISCO     ZPRP08-0729-01-MAR       08-0729-01           1               EA
MY01                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               CISCO     ZPRP10-2919-01$1         10-2919-01           1               EA
MY01                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               CISCO     ZPRP10-2919-01$1         10-2919-01           1               EA
MY01

[Datatable data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAImB.png)

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        string filepath = @"C:\Users\2563911\source\repos\test1.txt";
        using (System.IO.TextReader tr = File.OpenText(filepath))
        {
            string line;
            while ((line = tr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {

                if (!line.StartsWith("-"))
                {
                    if (line.Length < 82 || line.Contains("MY01"))
                    {        
                        string[] items = line.Replace("MY01","").Split(new string[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

                        if (dt.Columns.Count == 0 )
                        {
                            for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
                                dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column" + i, typeof(string)));                                

                        }
                        dt.Rows.Add(items);

                    }
                }
            }

            //show it in gridview
            this.DataGridView.DataSource = dt;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please provide some sample data and provide examples of the output you expect.

Comment: What do you mean by "merge"? That can mean very different things in different situations. Instead of the code to show your data, show us what your data looks like, and what you want it to look like after "merging". A few rows is enough.

Comment: Edited, please take a look ya

Comment: Maybe I am not seeing it, but all I can see is that "ZPRP 08-0729-01-MAR" is now "ZPRP08-0729-01-MAR" where the space between the "P" and the "0" is removed such that the form one value for a column?

Comment: Yes you are right

Comment: So you want a new table structure with five rows instead of six, whereby column 2 and column 3 are merged? (Keep in mind that column indexes are zero based).

Answer (score 0):

```
// The simple solution.
// Split the string at every space.
// Return a new array where you join or re-order the columns however you want.
string[] SplitIntoAndCombineColumns(string line)
{
    var parts = line.Split(' ');

    // Make sure our array is long enough.
    // If the string does not contain these fields,
    // they will be null in the result.
    if(parts.Length < 7) {
        Array.Resize(ref parts, 7);
    }

    var result = new[] {
        parts[0], parts[1], 
        // Combine these two columns
        parts[2] + parts[3],        
        parts[4], parts[5], parts[6]
    };

    return result;
}
```